# Nativescript observableArray with observable.fromObject - auto update view

Tags: nativescript

I am challenged to understand why it is not possible to push/append items to the observable.fromObject so as to update the view. This is odd to me but im probably missing something.

I am populating this:

```
//declare the viewmodel
    const viewModel = new observableModule.fromObject({
    //declare the properties of this viewmodel
    bulletins: []

});
```

with this json:

```
{"total_bulls":"664","GenericName":"Tocilizumab","brandName":"Actemra","drugCat":"(IL-6) Receptor Antagonist","bullID":4847,"fastURL":"https:\/\/gotopills.com\/?post_type=drug-bulletin&#038;p=4847","litAlertLvl":"High"}
```

It appears there is no way to add a new item using a push or set and instead it seems that the suggestion is to use the observableArray although i then lose the ability to auto-update the view :(

Comment: The thing is that you have a JS array - if you change the whole array the change will be detected as your object is changed. But when adding/removing array items (e.g. via push) this won't work as you are not changing the observable object `let arr = []; arr.push(1) // wont trigger change detection but arr = [1,2,3] // this will trigger`. However, this is why there is an ObservableArray in NativeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the odd way to do this is to drop the observableArray into the observable.fromObject as in:

```
viewModel.bulletins = new ObservableArray(r);
```

then do a push on the array:

```
viewModel.bulletins.push(element);
```

Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: `ObservableArray` is meant for handling updates on Array, this is the recommended way for {N} Core.